# Substances that pass visible light but absorb microwaves

Tags: water, materials, electromagnetic-radiation

Specifically, the substances should be water-miscible or water-soluble, but *not* water itself. Additionally, they should be absorptive but not opaque.

Comment: Water itself is such substance.

Comment: Ah right. I'm interested in substances other than water. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - ethanol and methanol (among others) are listed [here](http://cem.com/page130.html) as being "high absorbers" of microwave energy.